# Go to a URL with specific cookies to avoid a splash page

Tags: javascript, url, cookies, uri, url-routing

I want to give some clients a URL to our website that avoids the splash page (of which there is a cookie so they only view it one time). Is this possible to give someone a URL or line of javascript they can put in their address bar that can set a cookie before going to a site on the client-side?

I tried doing this in the address bar a bunch of different ways but nothing was working:

```
javascript:document.cookie=SPLASHCOOKIE=1;window.location.href="thesite.com";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You can not do it. Code will set cookie on the current domain.

Comment: Sorry for the follow up question, but why not? Can't you both set a cookie and direct the browser to a URL in javascript? Why can't you do both? Or can you not set your own cookies with javascript in the address bar?

Comment: Because you need to be on that domain to set the cookie.

Comment: Oh, ok, so it only will set a cookie for the page you're already on. So there's no way to set non-session cookies with js?

Comment: I admit, I'm kinda proud of myself for even coming up with a question that can't be done. That means I'm really starting to get it. Thanks!